# Installing qiskit with `pip install qiskit` gives `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1`

Tags: qiskit, programming

I have created a virtual environment by `virtualenv` (not `conda`) and tried to install qiskit by:

```
pip install qiskit
```

But it gives me a lot of error lines on the output:

```
Processing c:\users\mrt\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\20\f3\76\5a370641d58aa5f2887118316f675e967dd00c087276c5fc7d\qiskit-0.15.0-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.4.6 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from qiskit) (0.4.6)
Collecting qiskit-aqua==0.6.4
  Using cached qiskit_aqua-0.6.4-py3-none-any.whl (1.8 MB)
Collecting qiskit-aer==0.4.0
  Using cached qiskit-aer-0.4.0.tar.gz (10.0 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: qiskit-terra==0.12.0 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from qiskit) (0.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: qiskit-ignis==0.2.0 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from qiskit) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.19 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.4.6->qiskit) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: websockets<8,>=7 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.4.6->qiskit) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-ntlm>=1.1.0 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.4.6->qiskit) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: arrow>=0.15.5 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.4.6->qiskit) (0.15.5)
Requirement already satisfied: nest-asyncio!=1.1.0,>=1.0.0 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.4.6->qiskit) (1.2.3)
Collecting scikit-learn>=0.20.0
  Using cached scikit_learn-0.22.1-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl (5.5 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: sympy>=1.3 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.6.4->qiskit) (1.5.1)
Processing c:\users\mrt\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\78\55\c8\dc61e772445a566b7608a476d151e9dcaf4e092b01b0c4bc3c\dlx-1.0.4-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting quandl
  Using cached Quandl-3.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.0 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.6.4->qiskit) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema>=2.6 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.6.4->qiskit) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: fastdtw in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.6.4->qiskit) (0.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.6.4->qiskit) (1.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=40.1.0 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.6.4->qiskit) (45.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil>=5 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.6.4->qiskit) (5.6.7)
Requirement already satisfied: networkx>=2.2 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.6.4->qiskit) (2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: docplex in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aqua==0.6.4->qiskit) (2.12.182)
Collecting cvxopt; python_version < "3.8" or sys_platform != "win32"
  Using cached cvxopt-1.2.4.tar.gz (6.7 MB)
Collecting h5py
  Using cached h5py-2.10.0-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl (2.1 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: cython>=0.27.1 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aer==0.4.0->qiskit) (0.29.15)
Requirement already satisfied: pybind11>=2.4 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-aer==0.4.0->qiskit) (2.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: marshmallow-polyfield<6,>=5.7 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-terra==0.12.0->qiskit) (5.8)
Requirement already satisfied: marshmallow<4,>=3 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-terra==0.12.0->qiskit) (3.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: dill>=0.3 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-terra==0.12.0->qiskit) (0.3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: ply>=3.10 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from qiskit-terra==0.12.0->qiskit) (3.11)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.19->qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.4.6->qiskit) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.19->qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.4.6->qiskit) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.19->qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.4.6->qiskit) (2019.11.28)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.19->qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.4.6->qiskit) (1.25.8)
Requirement already satisfied: ntlm-auth>=1.0.2 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from requests-ntlm>=1.1.0->qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.4.6->qiskit) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=1.3 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from requests-ntlm>=1.1.0->qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.4.6->qiskit) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from arrow>=0.15.5->qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.4.6->qiskit) (2.8.1)
Collecting joblib>=0.11
  Using cached joblib-0.14.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (294 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: mpmath>=0.19 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from sympy>=1.3->qiskit-aqua==0.6.4->qiskit) (1.1.0)
Collecting more-itertools
  Using cached more_itertools-8.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (43 kB)
Processing c:\users\mrt\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\13\61\89\9192774c0f1e6c3342354df9f4804d7a9de80ac88e062d2e56\inflection-0.3.1-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from quandl->qiskit-aqua==0.6.4->qiskit) (1.14.0)
Collecting pandas>=0.14
  Using cached pandas-1.0.1-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl (7.7 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent>=0.14.0 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema>=2.6->qiskit-aqua==0.6.4->qiskit) (0.15.7)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.4.0 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema>=2.6->qiskit-aqua==0.6.4->qiskit) (19.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata; python_version < "3.8" in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema>=2.6->qiskit-aqua==0.6.4->qiskit) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator>=4.3.0 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from networkx>=2.2->qiskit-aqua==0.6.4->qiskit) (4.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: docloud>=1.0.375 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from docplex->qiskit-aqua==0.6.4->qiskit) (1.0.375)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=1.3->requests-ntlm>=1.1.0->qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.4.6->qiskit) (1.14.0)
Collecting pytz>=2017.2
  Using cached pytz-2019.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (509 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from importlib-metadata; python_version < "3.8"->jsonschema>=2.6->qiskit-aqua==0.6.4->qiskit) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in e:\py\quantum-computing\lib\site-packages (from cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8->cryptography>=1.3->requests-ntlm>=1.1.0->qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.4.6->qiskit) (2.19)
Building wheels for collected packages: qiskit-aer, cvxopt
  Building wheel for qiskit-aer (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'e:\py\quantum-computing\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\MRT\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6b8z6utw\\qiskit-aer\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MRT\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6b8z6utw\\qiskit-aer\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\MRT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ygy91648'
       cwd: C:\Users\MRT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6b8z6utw\qiskit-aer\
  Complete output (153 lines):


  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 15 2017 v141)" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/MRT/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-6b8z6utw/qiskit-aer/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 15 2017 v141)" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "Visual Studio 15 2017 v141" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
    Generator

      Visual Studio 15 2017

    could not find any instance of Visual Studio.



  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/MRT/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-6b8z6utw/qiskit-aer/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "Visual Studio 15 2017 v141" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 15 2017 v141)" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  -- The C compiler identification is unknown
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (ENABLE_LANGUAGE):
    The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

      cl

    is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

    To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
    that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
    unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
    Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

    Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
    variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
    the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/MRT/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-6b8z6utw/qiskit-aer/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  See also "C:/Users/MRT/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-6b8z6utw/qiskit-aer/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 15 2017 v141)" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "NMake Makefiles JOM (Visual Studio 15 2017 v141)" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  -- The C compiler identification is unknown
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (ENABLE_LANGUAGE):
    The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

      cl

    is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

    To use the JOM generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
    that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
    unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
    Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

    Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
    variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
    the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/MRT/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-6b8z6utw/qiskit-aer/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  See also "C:/Users/MRT/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-6b8z6utw/qiskit-aer/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "NMake Makefiles JOM (Visual Studio 15 2017 v141)" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  ********************************************************************************
  scikit-build could not get a working generator for your system. Aborting build.

  Building windows wheels for Python 3.7 requires Microsoft Visual Studio 2017.
  Get it with "Visual Studio 2017":

    https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/

  ********************************************************************************
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for qiskit-aer
  Running setup.py clean for qiskit-aer
  Building wheel for cvxopt (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'e:\py\quantum-computing\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\MRT\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6b8z6utw\\cvxopt\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MRT\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6b8z6utw\\cvxopt\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\MRT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-03pa82mg'
       cwd: C:\Users\MRT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6b8z6utw\cvxopt\
  Complete output (21 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cvxopt
  copying src\python\coneprog.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cvxopt
  copying src\python\cvxprog.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cvxopt
  copying src\python\info.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cvxopt
  copying src\python\misc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cvxopt
  copying src\python\modeling.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cvxopt
  copying src\python\msk.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cvxopt
  copying src\python\printing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cvxopt
  copying src\python\solvers.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cvxopt
  copying src\python\_version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cvxopt
  copying src\python\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cvxopt
  UPDATING build\lib.win32-3.7\cvxopt/_version.py
  set build\lib.win32-3.7\cvxopt/_version.py to '1.2.4'
  running build_ext
  building 'base' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cvxopt
  Running setup.py clean for cvxopt
Failed to build qiskit-aer cvxopt
Installing collected packages: joblib, scikit-learn, dlx, more-itertools, inflection, pytz, pandas, quandl, cvxopt, h5py, qiskit-aqua, qiskit-aer, qiskit
    Running setup.py install for cvxopt ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'e:\py\quantum-computing\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\MRT\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6b8z6utw\\cvxopt\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MRT\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6b8z6utw\\cvxopt\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\MRT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-u6cvqizo\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'e:\py\quantum-computing\include\site\python3.7\cvxopt'
         cwd: C:\Users\MRT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6b8z6utw\cvxopt\
    Complete output (21 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cvxopt
    copying src\python\coneprog.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cvxopt
    copying src\python\cvxprog.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cvxopt
    copying src\python\info.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cvxopt
    copying src\python\misc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cvxopt
    copying src\python\modeling.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cvxopt
    copying src\python\msk.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cvxopt
    copying src\python\printing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cvxopt
    copying src\python\solvers.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cvxopt
    copying src\python\_version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cvxopt
    copying src\python\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cvxopt
    UPDATING build\lib.win32-3.7\cvxopt/_version.py
    set build\lib.win32-3.7\cvxopt/_version.py to '1.2.4'
    running build_ext
    building 'base' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'e:\py\quantum-computing\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\MRT\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6b8z6utw\\cvxopt\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MRT\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6b8z6utw\\cvxopt\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\MRT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-u6cvqizo\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'e:\py\quantum-computing\include\site\python3.7\cvxopt' Check the logs for full command output.
```

System description:

```
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Windows 10 x64
```

What are the requirements? What should I do to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a general software installation question, not directly related to QC

Comment: @luciano Agreed, but SOF is not that much comfortable.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like `qiskit` does not support Python 3.9.x yet. Make sure to create your environment with the latest Python 3.8.x instead. Here are the steps to resolve the issue:

1. Create your virtual environment:

```
$ conda create -n my-quantum-env python=3.8
```

2. Activate your environment:

```
$ conda activate my-quantum-env
```

3. Install `qiskit`.

```
(my-quantum-env) $ pip install qiskit
```

Comment: I'd like to share that I've successfully installed qiskit using version 3.8.7, after following Bruno suggestions, while with version 3.9 was failed. Thanks Bruno.

Comment: What value does this answer give? It is same as I wrote just a change in version number

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with installing on the default root conda environment, which already has the required dependencies. Solve by running it on a different conda environment.

**Create a Conda Environment**

```
conda create -n name_of_my_env python=3
```

**Activate the Conda Environment**

```
source activate name_of_my_env
```

**Install the QiSkit Package**

```
pip install qiskit
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but as I mentioned, I've used `virtualenv` without any IDE, etc like Conda.

Comment: Did you tried creating another environment?

Comment: Not yet. My intention has changed, however, I'll give another env a go.

Comment: Ok Great!. Please reply after trying out.

Comment: I am exactly doing this with no luck. I am on Windows 10 and I also tried running Conda in Admin mode as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Removed Python 3.9 and installed the 3.8 version. That did the trick.

Comment: Note: other languages / frameworks don't do this. It is specifically a python thing.

Answer (score 1):

It appears pip is trying to compile qiskit-aer (the C++ simulators) from source and failing since it doesn't have visual studio installed (I guess you're on Windows). This should not happen in the sense that it should simply download a precompiled wheel.

My guess is that you have a cached previous install attempt. To ignore it, try:

`pip install qiskit --no-cache-dir`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have been running this command but it just re-download dependencies and finally got me the same error.

Comment: Looking at https://pypi.org/project/qiskit-aer/#files, it seems that indeed there is no precompiled wheel for 32-bit windows. My suggestion is to ensure your virtuanenv is configured to use 64-bit Python

Comment: Honestly, I have guessed the problem is with the 32bit Python. Gonna change this stuff and report here.

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to the same issue, here's the solution. It's because the base env for python is version 3.8.3 while any new env you activate is version 3.9 which isn't compatible with qiskit. So after activating your environment, run the command:
`conda install python=3.8.3`
and then run
`pip install qiskit`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `venv`, you can try downloading Python 3.8 and run a virtual env pointing to that python installation. Installing qiskit in there should succeed.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1534343